# How to correctly import a raster file with these metadatas into Tilemill?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, tilemill

I have a GeoTIFF file for which *gdalsrsinfo* reports this:

```
PROJ.4 : '+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]
```

If I try to import that file into Tilemill, I cannot view it properly. If I chose to let Tilemill autodetect the SRS, it fails:

```
Unable to determine SRS for layer "antani2" at /home/strappanai/antani2.tiff
```

If in Tilemill I specify a Custom PROJ.4 string instead, that is, the one I get from gdalsrsinfo (and from QGIS as well), that is

**+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs**

then the layer actually  *gets* imported, but it is showed significantly tilted to the right - not as expected.

I don't know if this may matter to any extent, but QGIS imports and visualizes the file perfectly fine.

I also tried to reproject the source file as instructed here: 
https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/reprojecting-geotiff/

But gdalwarp returns this error a thousand times and then fails:

```
ERROR 1: Too many points (441 out of 441) failed to transform,
unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window     3593619,2225230,6394,6394, skipping.
More than 1000 errors or warnings have been reported. No more will be reported from now.
```

EDIT:
This is the Layer Extent given by QGIS.

Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
638153.2011202700668946,5115644.8502587005496025 : 662908.4373886700486764,5132649.3878203006461263

**Here's an identically behaving file:**
[sample file](https://mega.nz/#!UZBQnJAD!gNbojYu1OZc31Z_Hug4zosQuVrbXe5jO3J2Ra1xt2yk)

And here's how it's pictured in QGIS and in Tilemill (QGIS reads the SRS from the file, I specify the PROJ.4 string into Tilemill as stated above as it can't read it out from the TIFF).

[image]

Comment: Can you add the extent of the layer, as reported by QGIS with Rightclick on the layer, metadata tab?

Comment: It seems there is something unusual going on with your data. To give you an correct answer it would be great to get access to the data as they seem the act strange when you try to transform them. My first suggestion would be to copy the data using gdal_translate and define the output srs.

Comment: I added the layer extents as requested.

I am afraid I cannod share the data being it unfortunately copyrighted, sorry.

I also tried to gdal_transform the data but without success (maybe I did it the wrong way. Actually don't even remember _how_ right now.

Comment: if i understand the error message correctly, gdalwarp finds GCPs within the image and tries to warp based on them. Somehow this seems not to work. Which reprojection method did you choose? gdalwarp says "The default is to select a polynomial order based on the number of GCPs". Maybe it would be better to use a different one.

Comment: Tilemill should project the file correctly nevertheless without the need to warp it actually. According to the instructions, warping is recommended only for big sources so to reduce load on Tilemill for reprojecting the data. warping is opny optional.

Comment: I added a file that behaves the same way. You can play with that. Thanks so much.

Comment: I used warp and translate. Both just worked fine without any error messages.

Comment: Maybe I found your problem. On the Tilemill website it is stated "Since Mapnik is currently unable to reproject raster data sources, to load them in TileMill you must ensure they are in Web Mercator projection."

Comment: The site also tells that:

Adding a non-Mercator GeoTIFF to TileMill

*If you’re working with a small GeoTIFF* or just want to quickly preview something that is not already projected to Web Mercator, *you can skip the initial reprojection step and add the file directly to TileMill. To do this you will need to know the spatial reference system (SRS) of your file so you can tell TileMill.*

Source: https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/reprojecting-geotiff/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29623/discussion-between-generic-militzer-and-dakatine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested a bit with your example file. The solution was the following. I reprojected the file to WGS84 using QGIS and then added it to my Tilemill project defining the projection as WGS84.

The gdal command is as follows:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:32632 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -of GTiff antanired.tiff antanired_warp_WGS84.tiff
```

As you can see in the example it works with your provided data. But it failed leaving the settings on auto detect srs.

[image]

The tilting of the image to the right it only caused by srs differences. While the image is perfectly rectangular in UTM it will be a bit squeezed when it is shown in WGS84. The same will be true if you do it the other way around.

**UPDATE**

You might get rid of the black background by passing

```
nodata="0"
```

to the Advanced field during raster upload. As it is shown for Landsat data [here](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/landsat-8-imagery/)

To give you the final answer to your question: **The import is absolutely correct!** 
Part of your error was the missing understanding of raster files and projections. I hope the trick with nodata definition works.

Comment: Thank you. Would you kindly be able to find a way to reproject it using any command line tool? I need to batch process plenty of data and using a GUI woulnd't be feasible. I try using gdalwarp:

gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:32632 -t_srs EPSG:3857 antanired.tiff antanired-3857.tiff

With no success.

Comment: I also used gdalwarp, but only in QGIS. I will edit my answer and include it.

Comment: As tilemill is not longer developed why don't you change to mapbox studio. Maybe you could change the complete project to UTM there.

Comment: wait. I also got that result, but it shows black tilted borders around the area. That is not what I need. I need it to be shown horizontally just as in qgis, with no artifacts. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, horizontally will not be possible. It is now shown (correctly geolocated) in WGS 84. Horizontally is only possible if the tilemill project would be UTM.

Comment: Here is your limitation, which will always lead to the black parts. As long as your input data are a clean square in UTM. "TileMill maps are always projected as ‘Web Mercator’ "

Comment: LOL. The page of Mabox Studio stated that it was in private beta so I tought that tilemill was the most up-to-date version of this software. Actually, mapbox studio can be downloaded. Going to try.